# Is this PBKDF2 java implementation, a good implementation? Is up to date?

Tags: java, passwords, pbkdf2

Is this a good implementation of PBKDF2?
https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode

I'm not sure that is a good idea to store password like:
`pass = PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" + toHex(salt) + ":" +  toHex(hash);`

Is there some other implementation?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with `pass = PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" + toHex(salt) + ":" + toHex(hash);`?

Comment: PBKDF2_ITERATIONS is plaintext, colons may provide information to the attacker.

Comment: PBKDF2 is designed to be resistant to attackers who *have your entire database, and your entire code*. In that case, not knowing the format of the password would be only a tiny speed bump for the attacker (they can just find it in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cryptography based on secrecy will *never* work for any measurable duration of time.

When implementing a KDF like PBKDF#2 certain parameters are allowed to be known by the "public" as they are essential for proper usage. Being cryptic in your returned password isn't going to deter attackers for any measurable amounts of duration because you **have** to assume that they can reverse engineer your software with ease (lets face it, if they're going up against PBKDF#2, they probably can).

Not including the iteration count anywhere is like not including the salt or hash, at the same time, the value for the iteration count is as safe to transmit as the salt and hash. And working on the principal that attackers can reverse engineer your code, colon or no colon isn't some barrier in their way, *they will find out eventually anyway*.

Regarding if Java's PBKDF#2 is "good" I cannot give any solid facts on that. But considering its one of the most important cryptographic functions within the java crypto library I would assume it be one of the best implementations possible in java (not considering 3rd party libraries that make use of hardware-accelerated native code, thats cheating).